# npm ERR! code ENOENT during npm start . It is showing this error also the same whenever I try to make a new react app

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319237/npm-start-errors-with-err-code-enoent-syscall-open) helps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.